# Indirect preprocessor substitution C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way a macro can use a value of a define passed to it, rather than the define text itself?

This is an odd example which I expected would be possible with the preprocessor.

A **C** file called `test.c` which includes itself twice to define two different functions which are called from `main`.

```
#ifndef IS_INDIRECT
#define IS_INDIRECT

/* int */
#define NUMTYPE int
#define PREFIX int_

#include "test.c"

#undef NUMTYPE
#undef PREFIX

/* short */
#define NUMTYPE float
#define PREFIX float_

#include "test.c"

#undef NUMTYPE
#undef PREFIX

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    printf("test int %d\n", int_squared(4));
    printf("test float %f\n", float_squared(2.5));

    return 0;
}

#else

/* function body */

#define fn(prefix, id) prefix ## id

NUMTYPE fn(PREFIX, squared)(NUMTYPE val)
{
    return val * val;
}

#endif
```

Gives the following error:

```
In file included from test.c:18:0:
test.c:37:12: error: conflicting types for 'PREFIXsquared'
 NUMTYPE fn(PREFIX, squared)(NUMTYPE val)
            ^
test.c:35:24: note: in definition of macro 'fn'
 #define fn(prefix, id) prefix ## id
                        ^
In file included from test.c:9:0:
test.c:37:12: note: previous definition of 'PREFIXsquared' was here
 NUMTYPE fn(PREFIX, squared)(NUMTYPE val)
            ^
test.c:35:24: note: in definition of macro 'fn'
 #define fn(prefix, id) prefix ## id
```

I would like to have the macro expand PREFIX to the value it's defined as, so I get `int_squared` not `PREFIXsquared`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it something like that you're looking for?

```
#define xxx(x,y)   x##y
#define CONCAT(x, y)  xxx(x, y)


#define function(type, operation, prm) type CONCAT(operation, type) (type prm)

function (int, square_, value) // int square_int (int value)
{
    return value * value;
}
```

The indirect use of `##` allows to define a macro that uses concatenation (`function`in our example). `CONCAT` is expanded to `xxx` when the macro is ***defined***,
and resolved to `x##y` when the macro is ***invoked***.

EDIT: added thanks to various contributors:

- `##` is called the token-pasting operator, or sometimes the token-concatenation operator
- more detailed explanations on C/C++ preprocessor [arguments prescan](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan)
- an [interesting blog article](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/12/abusing-the-c-preprocessor/) on the subject
- If you pore over the incredibly obfuscated list of obscure and arbitrary reserved identifiers added by the ISO guys (you'll have to cough up [about $200](https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html) to get the real spec, or resort to [second hand information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers), or ask your favourite guru for that bit of lore), you'll eventually notice it includes those beginning with a single underscore and also with two or more, so my "_CONCAT" became "xxx".

Frankly they made such a mess of C that I would no longer dare using the language in a professional environment. I'm so glad my IT days are over.

Comment: Great, this works, If I were to want to read up on this specific usage of the pre-processor, is there some common terms associated with cases where macro-calling-macro is needed?

Comment: I don't really know about theories behind this trick. At the time I first stumbled on this problem, the Internet was not so programmer-friendly (at least seen from France), so I had to figure it out all by myself. But the K&R is a masterpiece, and the solution is there if you read it carefully :). I found [this quite thorough and interesting article on the subject](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/12/abusing-the-c-preprocessor/), though it does not seem to rely on a specific theory either.

Comment: The reason this works is that there is a prescan that handles expansions - but there is no second prescan. This is so that if there are nested calls to a macro things work. I suspect this is just an... exploit of that :).  You can read more about that here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan

Comment: FYI, `##` is called the token-pasting operator, or sometimes the token-concatenation operator.

Comment: Please note that _CONCAT is a [reserved identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) and should therefore note be used

Comment: Unfortunately, adding another underscore won't suffice : `« All identifiers that begin with an underscore and [...] another underscore are always reserved for any use »`. In C, it is fine if you let a few trailing underscore though (not in C++, but fortunately it's a C question). If you want to refer to the C standard for free, you can use the [open-std](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) website (C11 draft linked) that provides you the latest drafts, which should be pretty close to the actual standard (in our case we are insterested in 7.1.3,  Reserved identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) as well:

**funcs_x.h**

```
/* N.B. no guard macro */
FUNC(int)
FUNC(float)
```

**main.c**

```
#define FUNC(x_) static x_ x_ ## _squared ( x_ val ) { return val * val; }
#include "funcs_x.h"
#undef FUNC


int main(int argc, const char **argv) { ... }
```

Which seems like what you are trying to do.